# how can i prove: $|P(\Bbb R)\times \Bbb R|=|P(\Bbb R)|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that $|P(\Bbb R)\times \Bbb R|=|P(\Bbb R)|$?

I can use the following statements:

$$|A|<|P(A)| $$$$
|P(\Bbb N)|=|\Bbb R|$$$$
|\Bbb R\times\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R|$$$$
|\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z|=|\Bbb Z|$$$$
|\Bbb Z|=|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0$$

I tried a lot, but I'm stuck.

thanks.

Comment: @Pedro: When writing in Hebrew text (without reasonable mathematical rendering) it's more than common to write `0א`. Remember that we write right-to-left.

Comment: I certainly didn't expect that to be the explanation =D @Asaf

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Prove that $|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\times\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|=|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|$. The proof is similar to that of $|\Bbb{R\times R}|=|\Bbb R|$. Then find some nice inequalities to bound $|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\times\Bbb R|$ from above and below by sets of the same size as $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.